# C++ word count program using C Strings errors out after program runs

Tags: c++

I am having problems with the following code once the string gets to around 24~ characters. It will run through the code just fine and calculate the correct amount of words in the string but it will error on strings containing more than a few words.  You can try inputting your name in 3 or 4 times and it errors out for me. I ran the debug option and it shows the error at line 74 which is the last closing bracket for the main function.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class WordCounter
{
private:
  string tempInput;
  int wordCount;
  int arraySize;
  char characterArray[];
public:
  WordCounter()
  {
    tempInput = "";
    wordCount = 0;
    arraySize = 0;
  }
  void getCharString()
  {
    cout << "Enter the sentence you would like a word count for:\n";
    getline(cin, tempInput);
  }
  void setArraySize()
  {
    arraySize = tempInput.length();
  }
  void convertStringToCharArray()
  {
    for(int counter = 0; counter < arraySize; counter++)
    {
        characterArray[counter] = tempInput[counter];
    }
  }
  int countNumOfWords()
  {
    int charCount;
    for(int counter = 0; counter < arraySize; counter++)
    {
        if(characterArray[counter] == '\n')
        {
            return 0;
        }
        if(characterArray[counter] == ' ')
        {
            charCount = 0;
        }
        else if(++charCount == 1)
        {
            wordCount++;
        }

    }
    return wordCount;
  }
};

int main()
{
WordCounter wordOne;

wordOne.getCharString();
wordOne.setArraySize();
wordOne.convertStringToCharArray();


int numberOfWords = wordOne.countNumOfWords();

cout << "The number of words in the sentence is " << numberOfWords << ".\n";


 return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char characterArray[];` points to unallocated memory. Writing there is undefined behavior. BTW, why do you need that at all?

Comment: Use `std::string`, as it can grow dynamically to handle various length texts.  Arrays of characters are fixed length and don't expand; you will have to perform any expansion.

Comment: It's for a C++ problem I'm doing for college. It's following along with the "Starting Out With C++ Early Objects Ninth Edition" Book

Comment: @TheOneLandon It's quite silly to fallback to c-strings when already using `std::string`. It seems that book isn't a very helpful resource for learning.

Comment: @user0042 I agree, especially since this is much later in the book and considered more advanced C++ topics.

Comment: @TheOneLandon If the book actually taught "more advanced C++", it would have demonstrated something [like this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/52483f267bb00842)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a function that count words in a string, where words are splited by whitespaces character, you can just use a regex :

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <regex>

size_t countNumOfWords(std::string s) {
    std::regex wordCountRegex("[^ ]+");
    std::smatch matches;
    size_t nb_words = 0;
    while (std::regex_search(s, matches, wordCountRegex)) {
        s = matches.suffix().str();
        ++nb_words;
    }
    return nb_words;
}
```

Or continue with the same code you had before :

```cpp
  int countNumOfWords(const std::string& s)
  {
    int charCount;
    for(int counter = 0; counter < s.length(); counter++)
    {
        if(s[counter] == '\n')
        {
            return 0;
        }
        if(s[counter] == ' ')
        {
            charCount = 0;
        }
        else if(++charCount == 1)
        {
            wordCount++;
        }

    }
    return wordCount;
}
```

However, if you want to continue using your code, you will have to make several modifications :

- The field `characterArray` is never initialized, and no memory allocation is done. The value of characterArray ( which is a pointer to char ) is completely random, and accessing it through the subscript operator results in **undefined behavior** ( which means that the program could crash, or corrupt variables, or do nothing detectable, and that make debugging very hard ). You might want to add `characterArray = new char[arraySize];` in the `convertStringToCharArray()` method
- Speaking about converting `std::string` to char array, you might want to replace the code in the `convertStringToCharArray()` method by that : `characterterArray = tempInput.c_str()`. `std::string::c_str()` method return the internal value of the pointer in your `std::string` object, and points to the memory location where a char array has been allocated. You should not delete it
- Based on the previous point, you might want to only use the `std::string` field, which has his own size information ( making `arraySize` field useless ) and his own char array ( making `characterArray` field useless ).